# Change C signature to accept instead of array of ints, an array of chars

Tags: c, pointers, casting, char, int

I first must admit that I am not a C expert, and I always get mixed up when having to do such conversions.
I have the next function which takes in the first 2 parameters, 2 pointers to arrays of **unsigned ints**. How can I change the algorithm to accept instead 2 pointers to arrays of **unsigned chars**, and of course operate over these 2 arrays of char pointers? (I mean I know is not only to change the signature, but what should I change in the algorithm, too?)

this is what I need:

```
void resize(unsigned char *input, unsigned char *output, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
```

This is what I have:

```
void resize(unsigned int *input, unsigned int *output, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) 
{    
    int a, b, c, d, x, y, index;
    float x_ratio = ((float)(sourceWidth - 1)) / targetWidth;
    float y_ratio = ((float)(sourceHeight - 1)) / targetHeight;
    float x_diff, y_diff, blue, red, green ;
    int offset = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < targetHeight; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < targetWidth; j++) 
        {
            x = (int)(x_ratio * j) ;
            y = (int)(y_ratio * i) ;
            x_diff = (x_ratio * j) - x ;
            y_diff = (y_ratio * i) - y ;
            index = (y * sourceWidth + x) ;                
            a = input[index] ;
            b = input[index + 1] ;
            c = input[index + sourceWidth] ;
            d = input[index + sourceWidth + 1] ;

            // blue element
            blue = (a&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + (b&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                   (c&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + (d&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            // green element
            green = ((a>>8)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                    ((c>>8)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            // red element
            red = ((a>>16)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                  ((c>>16)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            output [offset++] = 
                    0x000000ff | // alpha
                    ((((int)red)   << 24)&0xff0000) |
                    ((((int)green) << 16)&0xff00) |
                    ((((int)blue)  << 8)&0xff00);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, why do you need it to be a different type - the reason I ask is that there are different solutions depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Most likely, what you actually want to do is cast the pointers going into the function.

Comment: What is C/C++ ? These are two different languages.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your `resize` function doesn't take pointers to arrays of `unsigned int`. It takes pointers to `unsigned int` -- each of which happens to point to the first element of an array. You *can* have actual pointers to arrays, but arrays are usually manipulated via pointers to their elements, not pointers to the array as a whole.

Comment: What do mean by "change to accept unsigned chars"?  The algorithm in the function expects 32 bits of data for each input element and generates 32 bits of data for each output -- an unsigned char only holds 8 bits.  Where do expect the other 24 bits to come from or go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code has:

```
int a, b, c, d, x, y, index;
...

for (int i = 0; i < targetHeight; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < targetWidth; j++) 
    {
        ...            
        a = input[index] ;
        b = input[index + 1] ;
        c = input[index + sourceWidth] ;
        d = input[index + sourceWidth + 1] ;

        // blue element
        blue = (a&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + (b&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
               (c&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + (d&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

        // green element
        green = ((a>>8)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                ((c>>8)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

        // red element
        red = ((a>>16)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
              ((c>>16)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);
```

The shifting operations for `green` and `red` mean that the code assumes there are 3 bytes worth of data in each value from `input`, which is fine when the type of `input` is `unsigned int *`.  If you change the input type to `unsigned char *`, however, you have to decide whether you only have blue data (no red or green component), or whether there will be three consecutive characters supplying blue, red and green components (or any other ordering; it's usually RGB, isn't it?), or whether there is some other arrangement.

If you have 3 consecutive components, you'll be able to do without the masking (`& 0xFF`) but you'll need to access the array more often.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code requires access to the pixels with 4 byte data type the best would be to do a cast at the beginning of your function:

```
void resize(unsigned char *input_char, unsigned char *output_char, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) 
{    
    unsigned int* input = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(input_char);        
    unsigned int* output = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(output_char);
    int a, b, c, d, x, y, index;
    //...
}
```

Note: the values int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight must refer to the integer-size of the arrays, otherwise your code will not work proberly or raiser errors.

Here the code if you can not use C++ style cast:

```
void resize(unsigned char *input_char, unsigned char *output_char, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) 
{    
    unsigned int* input = (unsigned int*)(input_char);        
    unsigned int* output = (unsigned int*)(output_char);
    int a, b, c, d, x, y, index;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Since the question is tagges C, and not C++, I suspect a C++ solution isn't quite right.

Comment: The Title says C/C++ so I thought C++ would be OK

Comment: Independently of the C/C++ controversy (OK - I exaggerate; mild debate), the reinterpret cast is not appropriate on several grounds.  First, the incoming arrays may not be aligned so that it is safe to cast the pointer.  Second, it means that four times as much space is being accessed as is allocated (assuming `sizeof(char) * 4 == sizeof(int)`).